# Where is defined include_path in yii framework?

Tags: php, windows, apache, yii

The question: Where is defined include_path? 
I try to run PhpUnit tests. I cd to project folder and use command: 
"phpunit/functional/SiteTest.php". The command line output:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\projects\demo\protected\tests>phpunit  functional/SiteTest.php

Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php): failed 

to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 

'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs

\yii\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php on line 12
```

Where is defined include_path? I need to change include directory, in my case it is c:xampp\php, not c:\xampp\php\PEAR.

The contents of config/main.php:

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'amber',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            //'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        /*
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        */
        /*'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),*/
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=trackstar_dev',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            //'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Where is defined include_path? I need to change include directory, in my case it is c:xampp\php, not c:\xampp\php\PEAR.

Comment: The include path is not defined in config/main.php

Answer (score 0):

I have used and modified advices from:
[http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16553-cant-get-phpunit-and-selenium-working-correctly/][1]
[http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/14995-wamp-netbeans-phpunit-selenium-yii/][2]

I went to: [http://pear.phpunit.de/][3]
downloaded: PHPUnit_Selenium 1.3.3
unipped and untarred
have copied contents from inner folder  `'C:\Users\Gintare\Downloads\PHPUnit_Selenium-1.3.3\PHPUnit_Selenium-1.3.3\PHPUnit_Selenium-1.3.3\PHPUnit\Extensions\'`
                    to folder `c:\xampp\php\PhpUnit\Extensions.`

PHPUnit tests start working.